# l3keys: how to "generate" `.inherit:V` variant of `.inherit:n`

Tags: l3keys

From the documentation,

```
⟨key⟩ .inherit:n = {⟨parents⟩}
Specifies that the ⟨key⟩ path should inherit the keys listed as ⟨parents⟩.
```

Because may parents are collected in `\l_MY_parents_clist`, I would benefit from

```
⟨key⟩ .inherit:V = \l_MY_parents_clist,
```

Unfortunately, the `.inherit:V` key variant does not exist, what can I do instead?

Below is a working code that uses an auxiliary function to create a keyval list from scratch and an auxiliary variable to store it. Isn't there something more efficient?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { parent, grand_parent }
\cs_set:Npn \MY_helper:Nn #1 #2 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 {
    child .inherit:n = { #2 },
  }
}
\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
\exp_args:NNV
\MY_helper:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_clist
\exp_args:NnV 
\keys_define:nn { } \l_tmpa_tl

TESTING:\\
\keys_define:nn { parent } {
  test .code:n = TEST: #1\\,
}
\keys_set:nn { child } {
  test = blah,
}
\keys_define:nn { grand_parent } {
  grand-test .code:n = GRAND-TEST: #1\\,
}
\keys_set:nn { child } {
  grand-test = blah,
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although key properties have `expl3`-like signatures, they have to be created internally a bit differently (as keyvals need delimited macros). As such, there's no interface to add this, although I can look at including in the next `expl3` release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure it more like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { parent, grand_parent }

\cs_set:Npn \MY_helper:nnn #1 #2 #3 {
     \keys_define:nn { #1 } {#2 .inherit:n = { #3 }}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \MY_helper:nnn {nnV}

\MY_helper:nnV {} {child} \l_tmpa_clist

TESTING:\\
\keys_define:nn { parent } {
  test .code:n = TEST: #1\\,
}
\keys_set:nn { child } {
  test = blah,
}
\keys_define:nn { grand_parent } {
  grand-test .code:n = GRAND-TEST: #1\\,
}
\keys_set:nn { child } {
  grand-test = blah,
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, To make this more general, `\MY_helper:n` could become `\MY_helper:nnn` where the <module> and the <key> are parameters

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS edit added